# sort fails in Python This is my .py.During the cycle solt does not work, why?

Tags: python

```
n = int(input())
pi = input().split()
lens = len(pi)
sum = 0
while lens!=1:
    pi.sort()
    print(pi)
    pi[0] = str(int(pi[0])+int(pi[1]))
    sum = sum + int(pi[0])
    print(sum)
    for i in range(1,lens-1):
        pi[i] = pi[i+1]
    del pi[-1]
    #print(pi)
    pi.sort()
    lens = len(pi)
print(sum)
```

This is my .py.During the cycle sort does not work, why?

```
5
5 8 3 2 9
['2', '3', '5', '8', '9']
5
['5', '5', '8', '9']
15
['10', '8', '9']
33
['18', '9']
60
60
```

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: Sorting _strings_ that contain numbers isn't the same as sorting the numbers themselves. `['18', '9']` is sorted correctly because the character `'1'` comes before the character `'9'`.

Comment: Start your interpreter and enter `'18' < '9'`. Note the result. (You need to work with integers, not with strings.)

Comment: Side note: `sum` is a builtin function of Python, so when you use `sum` for a variable name, you "shadow" it; basically you make the original `sum` inaccessible because that name now refers to your list. This is usually a bad idea, and can cause perplexing bugs down the road. (For that matter, why is your list named `pi`? It's not shadowing anything, but... you'd usually expect that to represent the mathematical constant...)

Comment: It is a simple algorithm that calculates，Huffman Tree，I want to implement this algorithm, I need to sort the array and delete and add the data in the array.